# ... is not how I am built

Tags: word-choice

is it possible to say "Resting on my laurels is not how I am built"? I am trying to use some expressive language in my cover letter and that's the best I could come up with. Thanks!

Comment: "Complacency is not in my vocabulary! ...oh except in that sentence, ... uhh.."

Comment: Possible? Yes. Understandable? Yes. Idiomatic and natural-sounding? No. If you make it “not what I’m built/made/meant for”, it at least becomes idiomatic. But expressive and suitable for a cover letter? Much more subjective, but I would say not really.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet “not what I’m built/made/meant for" sounds waaay better. Great advice, greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Good question. "Resting on my laurels" is an action, while "how I am built" suggests a property of an object or person. So those don't match up. If you insist on using a sentence like this, try "Resting on my laurels is not in my nature."

Alternatively, try a direct expression like "I don't rest on my laurels."  Also note that "rest on my laurels" would suggest you have received an honor or award of some kind (a "laurel"). If that's not accurate, try "rest on my accomplishments."

Better still, connect this continued effort to your experience: "Rather than rest on my accomplishments, I gained approval to lead 2 new improvement projects at work the following year."  Or simpler, "Building on these accomplishments, I gained approval...."

Stylistically, it's best to ground your statements in the facts of your experience rather than make an ungrounded claim, regardless of its expressiveness.

Comment: I like all of this advice, except for the phrase "rest on my accomplishments." It's always dangerous to mix metaphors and in this case, you end up combining a physical action with a non-physical object -> resting, i.e. lying down on accomplishments? Unless your accomplishment was building a couch...

Comment: I find "Resting on my laurels is not in my nature." a really good alternative. Thank you!

Comment: Wow, I never imagined someone "resting on their laurels" to be sitting or sleeping on a laurel wreath. Conjures up strange images. That said, while "laurel" is a metaphor, I don't think "resting on one's laurels" is strictly a metaphor, unless people actually do sit on their laurel wreaths! I suspect the expression has always meant "laurel" to mean "honor," not a physical object. If it only ever meant rest on one's honors, then the alternative I offered is fine. In any case, it's not being mixed with any other metaphor, so probably fine. And Google shows "accomplishments" is used widely.

Comment: A bit on the evolution of "rest on one's laurels": https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/rest-on-his-laurels.html